# Default browser keeps opening the same page when computer connects to a wifi network

Tags: macos, wireless-networking

As I said up there my mac acts strange. When I connect to any wifi network(network name or type is irrelevant), a webpage opening in my default browser(I tried and changed default browser but no luck. Same thing keeps happening.) which is called "http://vodafonemobile.wifi". This started when I installed Vodafone 3G Wifi Modem Software to my computer. Uninstalled it but no luck neither.

Anyone knows how can I stop this thing? It is really annoying.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems like Vodafone's Mac driver is made by novamedia.de

So:

1. Open the terminal and type

   ```
   sudo su
   ```

   and give your password when prompted.
2. Relocate the Vodaphone drivers

   ```
   mkdir /var/root/junk/
   mv /usr/local/bin/VMRServer /var/root/junk/
   mv /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/de.novamedia.VMRServer.plist /var/root/junk/
   ```
3. Then if you feel like it, use `mv` command on all the below as illustrated above for `VMRServer`:

   ```
   /private/var/db/BootCaches/20B0A940-FBCA-4880-A74D-40988C242D7A/app.de.novamedia.DeInstaller.playlist
   /private/var/db/BootCaches/20B0A940-FBCA-4880-A74D-40988C242D7A/app.de.novamedia.Vodafone Mobile Broadband.playlist
   /private/var/db/receipts/de.novamedia.helperTools.Uninstaller.pkg.bom
   /private/var/db/receipts/de.novamedia.helperTools.Uninstaller.pkg.plist
   /private/var/db/receipts/de.novamedia.helperTools.VodafoneUpdateManager.pkg.bom
   /private/var/db/receipts/de.novamedia.helperTools.VodafoneUpdateManager.pkg.plist
   /private/var/db/receipts/de.novamedia.opcofiles.LauncherSettings.pkg.bom
   /private/var/db/receipts/de.novamedia.opcofiles.LauncherSettings.pkg.plist
   /private/var/db/receipts/de.novamedia.opcofiles.Opcos.pkg.bom
   /private/var/db/receipts/de.novamedia.opcofiles.Opcos.pkg.plist
   /private/var/db/receipts/de.novamedia.TechnologyBase.bom
   /private/var/db/receipts/de.novamedia.TechnologyBase.plist
   /private/var/db/receipts/de.novamedia.vmrServerInstaller.de.novamedia.VMRServer.pkg.bom
   /private/var/db/receipts/de.novamedia.vmrServerInstaller.de.novamedia.VMRServer.pkg.bom
   /private/var/db/receipts/de.novamedia.vmrServerInstaller.de.novamedia.VMRServer.pkg.plist           
   /private/var/db/receipts/de.novamedia.vmrServerInstaller.de.novamedia.VMRServer.pkg.plist
   /private/var/db/receipts/de.novamedia.vmrServerInstaller.VMRServer.pkg.bom
   /private/var/db/receipts/de.novamedia.vmrServerInstaller.VMRServer.pkg.bom
   /private/var/db/receipts/de.novamedia.vmrServerInstaller.VMRServer.pkg.plist
   /private/var/db/receipts/de.novamedia.vmrServerInstaller.VMRServer.pkg.plist
   /private/var/db/receipts/de.novamedia.Vodafone Mobile Broadband Base.bom
   /private/var/db/receipts/de.novamedia.Vodafone Mobile Broadband Base.plist
   ```
4. Remove `vodafonemobile.wifi` from your `hosts` file:

   1. In the terminal, type

      sudo vi /etc/hosts
   2. Cursor to the line that says

      ```
      192.168.1.1     vodafonemobile.wifi
      ```
   3. Press <kbd>D</kbd>,<kbd>D</kbd>
   4. Press <kbd>Escape</kbd>,`:wq!`,<kbd>Enter</kbd>

   (you have to do this at step 4 because VMRServer just recreates this entry if you delete it.)
5. Reboot your machine

Comment: What exactly is all this doing, and why are you moving the files to some random folder instead of removing them?

Comment: Step 1 turns you into ROOT.
Step 2 removes the daemon or faceless background application and places it in a folder /var/root/junk
Step 3 gets rid of the config files and other stuff associated with vodafone, and puts it in the same place as step 2.
Step 4 removes the permanent DNS association of vodafonemobile.wifi with the IP address 192.168.1.1 (or 0.1, as the case may be).
Step 5 ensures that the daemon does not respawn or reload.

The reason to move the stuff to /var/root/junk, in other words, in a folder called "junk" in the root user's home, is just in case you want to undo these changes

Answer (score 1):

Go to Applications Folder, there's a directory called Vodafone Utilities. In there you'll find an app called "Uninstaller" or something like that -- run that and boom, that annoying thing is gone!

Answer (score 0):

If your default browser is safari, go to Safari > Preferences > general. Here you will find the homepage. You can set it to whatever url you want.

Comment: That applies to most browsers where you can change the default page opened on startup.

Answer (score -2):

The software probably didn't uninstall properly.

Either re-install then uninstall the software again or do a system restore to the point where the software was originally installed in the first place.

Failing that, do a registry search for the link and remove and keys where the value is 'vodafonemobile.wifi'*

*Be careful when modifying the registry.

Comment: OS X doesn't have a registry, but the page could be opened by a background process started by a plist in `{~,}/Library/Launch{Agents,Daemons}`.